# Error installing tensorflow in R: /Users/emmeran/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/pip: No such file or directory

Tags: r, tensorflow

After installing the `tensorflow` package for R from Github, and loading with `library(tensorflow)`, when doing `install_tensorflow()`, I get the error message below. I don't know how to get it to find the file or where I can even know where the file is. Thanks

```
install_tensorflow()

Using virtual environment '~/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate' ...

sh: /Users/emmeran/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

> Error: Error installing package(s): 'pip'
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In system2(pip, args) : error in running command

Comment: Have you tried: `install_tensorflow(method = "auto")`? If you do not have `pip` installed, it may automatically choose to install via `conda` if you have that installed.

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried to use auto method but it does not work either, I have been trying to install pip but it seems that it's not being installed in /Users/emmeran/.virtualenvs/r-reticulate/bin/pip, instead it is just in Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Library⁩ ▸ ⁨Python⁩ ▸ ⁨2.7⁩ ▸ ⁨site-packages